# Populate city drop down according to the condition in angular5

Tags: json, angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to display a cities name in the select box according to the country in the previous select box.I displayed the countries in the first select box  but on the click event i can not display the cities,i dont know how to access the nested json into html.Please help.

This is my json file

```
  [
   { 
  "countryName": "India", 
    "cities": [
      { 
          "id": 1, 
          "name": "Banglaore", 
          "founded": -200, 
          "beautiful": true, 
          "data": 123,
          "keywords": ["Kaveri", "River"] 
      },
      { 
          "id": 1, 
          "name": "Pune", 
          "founded": 0, 
          "beautiful": false, 
          "data": "no",
          "keywords": ["FSDF", "FS"] 
      }
  ]
},
{ 
  "countryName": "US", 
  "cities": [
      { 
          "id": 2, 
          "name": "CA", 
          "founded": -200, 
          "beautiful": true, 
          "data": 123,
          "keywords": ["RT", "SSF"] 
      },
      { 
          "id": 2, 
          "name": "NY", 
          "founded": 0, 
          "beautiful": false, 
          "data": "no",
          "keywords": ["GSG", "DG"] 
      }
  ]
}
]
```

app.component.ts file is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {


  constructor(private http: Http) { }
public myData;
public v;

ngOnInit(){

 this.http.get("assets/file.json")
  .map((res:Response)=> res.json())
  .subscribe(data =>{this.myData = data})

}



onChange(event): void {  // event will give you full breif of action
  const newVal = event.target.value;
this.v =newVal;















}
}
```

app.html file is

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)" >
    <option value="0">--All--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let d of myData">
        {{d.countryName}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br/>


  <br/>

  <select >
        <option value="0">--All--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let object of myData" value="object.countryName" [selected]="object.countryName === v">{{object.cities}}</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some confusion on `cities` and `states`, but I think this is kinda what you are looking for;

In your first dropdown you need something like this:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)" >
  <option value="0">--All--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let d of myData" [value]="d" >
    {{d.countryName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

So the value of your options matches the countryName, your onChange method will make sure that the `v` property will be set to the object (with country and cities) when it's changed

```
<select =>
  <option value="0">--All--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let city of v.cities" value="object.countryName">{{city.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Some side remarks: 
- you are currently "chaining" your rxjs operators (and changing the Observable prototype), since RxJs version 5.5.6 you can "pipe" them instead, I think this way of using operators will eventually go away. So if you can change this it's encouraged.
- You are using the "old" way of fetching data over Http, now `HttpClient` is encouraged.
- Have a look at Reactive Forms in Angular, it'll make your code cleaner and easier to reason about

Taking into account my remarks you could have something like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
    form = new FormGroup({
        country: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    })

    data$ = this.httpClient.get('assets/file.json').pipe(share());

    countries$ = this.data$.pipe(
        map(data => data.map(entry => entry.countryName)),
        startWith([])
    );

    cities$ = this.form.get('country').valueChanges.pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.data$)
        map(([selectedCountry, allData]) => {
            const entry = allData.find(item => item.countryName === selectedCountry);
            return entry.cities;
        })
        startWith([])
    );

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { 
    }
}
```

You'll have to add `formControlName` properties on your selected, and the select options will need an `async` pipe.
By using a form with formControls you don't need to have an `onChange` event. `countries$` get's generated out of the result of the data call, and `cities$` get's generated by the valueChanges of the countrySelect + taking the last value of the data call. It's pretty elegant.

Comment: Can u please tell me how will be my view page

Comment: <select class="form-group" formControlName="country">
    <option value="0">--All--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let d of myData" [value]="d" >
      {{d.countryName}}
    </option>
  </select><select>
        <option value="0">--All--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let city of v.cities" value="object.countryName">{{city.name}}</option>
      </select>

Comment: What do you mean, for the alternative way?